# TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a ticket system that creates a channel then sends an embed in that channel.

But I get the `TypeError Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`. This is my code snippet:

```js
const openedTicket = message.guild.channels.cache.find((r) => r.name === `${message.author.username}s-ticket`);

const openedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription("Support will be with you shortly." + "To close this ticket react with :lock:");

setTimeout(function () {
    client.channels
        .get(openedTicket.id)
        .send(openedEmbed)
        .then((msg) => {
            msg.react("");
        });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really easy to do. All you need is a `.then()` to move on. So in your case that would be:

```
message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}s-ticket`, {
    type: 'text',
    permissionOverwrites: [
        {
            allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
            id: message.author.id
        },
        {
            deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
            id: message.guild.id
        }
    ]
}).then(channel => {
    const openedEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setDescription("Support will be with you shortly." + "To close this ticket react with :lock:");

    setTimeout(function () {
        channel.send(openedEmbed)
            .then((msg) => {
                msg.react("");
            });
    }, 1000);
})
```

You had the right solution with your reaction already.

EDIT:

Your original code comes up empty because you very likely have some uppercase letters in your name however all discord text channels are all lowercase and spaces are replaces with dashes. So when you look for a channel you need to factor all that into your search. So your `openedTicket` constant should look like this

```
const openedTicket = message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === `${message.author.username}s-ticket`.replace(" ", "-").toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score -1):

Either the channel doesnt exist, or you need to use this:

```js
const openedTicket = message.guild.channels.cache.find(r => r.name === `${message.author.username}s-ticket`).id;
```

The `id` at the end means you dont have to have `openedTicket.id` and makes error trapping much easier.

Also, you need to add a `cache` to your `client.channels.get(openedTicket)`

=> `client.channels.cache.get(openedTicket)`

You should also fetch all channels to ensure that your bot searches them all:

```js
await message.guild.channels.fetch(); //using await, to return a promise
client.channels.cache.get(openedTicket);
```

Comment: Well it definitely gets created with that exact name here:
`message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}s-ticket`, {
            type: 'text',
            permissionOverwrites: [
                {
                    allow: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    id: message.author.id
                },
                {
                    deny: 'VIEW_CHANNEL',
                    id: message.guild.id
                }`

but the `cache.find(r => r.name === `${message.author.username}s-ticket`).id` you suggested doesnt work either :/

Comment: I still get Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: are you using the code above, or your original code?

Comment: The code above. My full code is [here](https://pastebin.com/fdGWppFe)

Comment: I will take a look